# NSMutableArray Not Being Set

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I'm trying to do some simple assignment, but coming up with different results and I can't figure out why.  Why does the first assignment below work and the second one not?

```
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = something approrpriate here;
[self  setLocationsArray:mutableFetchResults];
[switchViewController setLocationsArray:mutableFetchResults];

NSLog(@"1 - %@", self.locationsArray); // -> returns array
NSLog(@"2 - %@", switchViewController.locationsArray); // -> returns null
NSLog(@"3 - %@", mutableFetchResults); // -> returns array
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet `switchViewController` is `nil`.

Comment: Ugh. This was it.  For some awesome reason I had the init commented out.  Gracias.